# It is possible to remove space between series in Bar Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm struggling with this problem that I don't know if it is possible to solve.

[image: Example]

I want to remove the space from Orange series, which doesn't contain any data in Session 1.

I'm just using a sample code to make a small graphic.

```
var serie1 = new Series();
serie1.LegendText = "Banana";
serie1.Points.AddXY("Session 1", 15);
serie1.Points.AddXY("Session 2", 30);

var serie2 = new Series();
serie2.LegendText = "Orange";
serie2.Points.AddXY("Session 2", 25);

var serie3 = new Series();
serie3.LegendText = "Apple";
serie3.Points.AddXY("Session 1", 10);
serie3.Points.AddXY("Session 2", 15);

chart1.Series.Add(serie1);
chart1.Series.Add(serie2);
chart1.Series.Add(serie3);
chart1.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel();
```

Comment: What is chart?  Is this available in the .NET framework?  I've never heard of it.

Comment: a) no the actual gaps (between the series) can not easly, dynamically  and reliable be removed. You can try to play with axis.min-maximum and the width of the columns. b) the 'gap' you show is actually a missing DataPoint.

Comment: A graphic basically, this is in Windows Forms. @rory.ap

Comment: @rory: This is obviously a MSChart control directly availble in WinForms and ASP. WPF can host it.

Comment: That's inconvenient, thanks @TaW

Comment: You did notice that the gap you marked was actually a missing point or one with y-value of zero? (The former if the x-values are numbers.) - Also: I misspoke in my comment above: the actual gaps are, of,course, not between series but between x-values (Session1 and Session2 in your chart)!!

Comment: @TaW Yes, I was just trying to make many sorted charts in just one Chart control

Comment: Well, multiple charts in one chart control can be created by adding multiple chartares. When doing this it is usually a good idea to control the size (Position)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Comment: Have you tried EmptyPointStyle? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.emptypointstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: How can this help me? I'm not sure how to use it